# In RC circuit, what exactly does the unit impulse input represent?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Let \$v\$ be the voltage across capacitor, and
\$a=\frac{1}{RC}\$, then the differential equation representing RC circuit with input \$f(t)\$ is
$$\frac{dv}{dt}+av = af(t)$$

When \$\mathcal{f(t) = u(t)}\$,
I know the input is a constant dc voltage source of \$1V\$ turned on at \$t=0\$. All good here.

However when  \$\mathcal{f(t) = \delta(t)}\$,
I don't seem to understand what exactly the input is:
Is it an infinite voltage acting for \$0\$ seconds?
What does the integral of input represent? voltage? energy?

---

My thinking:

From high school physics, Impulse is Force x time. This is identical to change in momentum:
$$F = \frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t} \Rightarrow \Delta p = F\Delta t$$
So unit impulse when acted on an object, essentially changes the momentum of the object by 1 Newton Second. How to interpret impulse input in an RC circuit?

Comment: The goal of the Dirac is to find\$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) f(x) \, dx = f(0)\$. It turns out that the area under the Dirac must be:
\$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x)\, dx = 1\$. See some material under the [theory of distributions](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~stein/lehre/SoSem09/distrvo.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

The impulse, i.e. dirac delta, [isn't really a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/123249/31402).

With that said, integrating *I dt* or *V dt* still works as it should, dimensionally speaking. If we have input voltage \$1 [V]\delta(t)\$ into an uncharged capacitor, we produce a current of \$1 [V]\delta(t)/R\$ (amperes). Integrating that with respect to time gives us \$1 [V*s]/R\$, (coulombs); we use V = Q/C to determine that the voltage ends up 1 volt-second/(RC) immediately after the impulse.

Comment: 1/RC volt-second ? does this mean the  impulse input doesn't immediately charge the capacitor to 1V,  the area of unit  impulse function? I know you're right because unit impulse response is \$w(t) = ae^{-at}\$ which is just \$a\$ at \$t=0^+\$

Comment: Ok you're treating impulse input as voltage

Comment: @across The area of the impulse function isn't 1 V; it's 1 volt-second. Calling it 1 V is dimensionally inaccurate, and leads to confusing in later steps.

Comment: nanofarad now I see the elegance of sequence of your steps. Firstly you're treating \$\delta(t)\$ input as voltage. You're accounting for the resistor, the current is \$\delta(t)/R\$. Integrating current w.r.t time gives charge accumulated over capacitor. From this you get the voltage. you're awesome!

Comment: @across not a problem, very happy to help!